# Is it require to test Automation anywhere bot?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, automationanywhere

Can you explain about Automation Anywhere Bot Testing.
Automation anywhere Bot require to test by Testing team?
If yes then can you help me out about process & documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [Automation Anywhere Univesity](https://university.automationanywhere.com/), where you will find the detailed explanation on the bot and it's usage.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. We used the following process at the CoE I previously led:

1. Developer creates and tests bot locally
2. Developer tests bot on a new bot runner in the QA environment
3. Developer tests bot running "headless" in the QA environment
4. QA Team/Business Owner does some testing with the bot to be sure that it performs as expected while running headless
5. Bot is finally promoted to production after the prior development/testing has been documented.